# Reproductor de videos "embed" tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Es posible reproducir videos utilizando los "embed" que proporcionan algunas paginas como YouTube. Pero en una interfaz de tkinter?, Eh estado investigando pero solo he encontrado proyectos para reproducir videos descargados en el escritorio.

Comment: En tkinter no lo sé, pero al menos en pyside2 sí que es posible directamente meter un navegador dentro de la aplicacion. (Por si te interesa investigarlo).

Comment: @Saelyth Muchas gracias, Al fin tengo alguna pista :)